# Trying to get the first record for each day of the week in Rails via SQL if possible

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a weekly view of projects.  For each project I'm grabbing the first record for each day of the week.  It's important to me to always get the first record for that day, and know which weekdays have no records.  Right now I'm doing this with a separate SQL string for each project + day of week combo in a nested for loop.

This feels wrong.  It seems like I should be able to get this with ActiveRecord / SQL via Group By and Limit, and use Ruby/Rails to process the results. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.
– David

Comment: I'm not experienced with RR, but depending on what DBMS you're using you should be able to use a function to truncate the date or each record to remove the time so you just have the calendar date, and then group by that, and then select the min datetime from each group.  So your record are grouped by the truncated calendar date, and then you can get the record with the minimum time for each group.  If you share which DBMS this is targeted at, and some info about how your schema is designed, I could probably help with the syntax of the query.

Comment: I'm using Postgres. I think this general approach would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that do the job? (Using MySQL)

```
@projects = []
for day in 1..7
  @projects.push Project.where("DAYOFWEEK(project_date) = ?", day).where(:project_date => Time.now.all_week).order('project_date desc').first
end
#Time.now.all_week assumes you're working with Rails 3.2
```

Take a look at [DATEOFWEEK() in MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

You can test with

```
for pj in @project
  p pj.project_date if pj.project_date #nil if no project found
end
```

Comment: Hi Wawa. That's not too far from what I'm doing now.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to use on SQL / ActiveRecord call the get the first record for each project for each day of the current week.

Comment: If you're using Rails 3.2, there is a `Time.now.all_week()` method that you can use in your `where`. Take a look at my edit.
Anyway, I don't know why this feels wrong for you. It's totally OK.

Comment: This is a good solution to make it work.  I'm trying to see if there's a way to cut down on the numbers of queries.  I'll be pulling data for Projects x Services x 7 days of the week.  I found an article on solving this issue in pure SQL, but I'm not sure how to translate it into ActiveRecord: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php

Comment: In your case, I would go with a caching strategy: DB caching or HTML fragment caching. Thanks for the vote and the accepted answer.